# Процесс загрузки динамической библиотеки под Linux и Windows

Tags: c++, c, dll, g++

Есть динамическая библиотека в которой определена глобальная переменная.
Также определена функция `DllMain` Которая использует эту глобальную переменную:

```
std::string g_value("value");

//Windows 
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID /*lpReserved*/)
{
  //использование g_value;
}

//Linux
void start() __attribute__ ((constructor));
void start()
{
   //использование g_value;
}
```

Под Windows сначала инициализируются глобальные переменные а потом уже начинает выполнятся DllMain (это всегда так или порядок не определен строго?). Под Linux наоборот сначала выполняется `start`, а потом глобальные переменные.

Можно ли задать порядок выполнения? Сначала глобальные переменные а потом `start`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно задать порядок инициализации:

```
std::string g_value __attribute__((init_priority(101))) = "value";

void start() __attribute__((constructor(102)));

void start()
{
  // использование g_value;
}
```

Решение взято отсюда:

[Bug 52477 - Wrong initialization order? __attribute__((constructor)) vs static data access](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52477)

По результатам обсуждения бага, была дополнена документация ([6.31.1 Common Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)) и сказано, что для С++ порядок инициализации глобальных данных и функций с атрибутом `constructor` не определён и рекомендуется использовать атрибут `init_priority`:

> The `constructor` attribute causes the function to be called
>   automatically before execution enters `main ()`. Similarly, the
>   `destructor` attribute causes the function to be called automatically
>   after `main ()` completes or `exit ()` is called. Functions with these
>   attributes are useful for initializing data that is used implicitly
>   during the execution of the program.
>
> You may provide an optional integer priority to control the order in
>   which constructor and destructor functions are run. A constructor with
>   a smaller priority number runs before a constructor with a larger
>   priority number; the opposite relationship holds for destructors. So,
>   if you have a constructor that allocates a resource and a destructor
>   that deallocates the same resource, both functions typically have the
>   same priority. The priorities for constructor and destructor functions
>   are the same as those specified for namespace-scope C++ objects (see
>   C++ Attributes). **However, at present, the order in which constructors
>   for C++ objects with static storage duration and functions decorated
>   with attribute `constructor` are invoked is unspecified. In mixed
>   declarations, attribute `init_priority` can be used to impose a specific
>   ordering.**

Comment: Интересно, как эти `init_priority` реализуются на уровне линкера (порядок в котором адреса секций .ctors, .init попадают в соответствующие массивы)?